Why does concentrated acid react differently to metals than dilute acid
I am asking this because the answers on this Stack Exchange all have 2 severe problems which have  not been asked. Why does concentrated acid (98% sulfuric, 75% nitric etc) react differently with metals. In stack exchange, we say the reason is due to oxidizing power of nitrate and sulphate in concentrated acid while in dilute acid, these are spectator ions and the hydronium ions mainly participate. I understand this but I have two fundamental questions - both are linked so strongly, I thought I would put them together.
In relation to the actual composition of the concentrated acid, why doesn't the sulphate and nitrate oxidize in dilute acid as they are in dilute acid along with hydronium. And why even is sulphate in this, I thought at really high concentration where the actual acid becomes the solvent, the undissociated acid molecules (confirmed that for e.g in sulfuric acid, majority of it is H2SO4 molecules on this stack exchange which can also decompose. Also confirmed in certain mechanism) are the main proton donors as conc. acid composed of acid molecules due to the lack of water. Yet how are we getting sulphate ions and nitrate ions?

Why do you post from guest ('unregistered') account? I think you should make an ordinary account and ask for merging the old one.

If you're referring to other posts, you should link them.

Generally, oxidating oxoacids have much stronger effects that their anions. Plus when concentrated, absence of (enough) water as hydrating solvent keeps many of molecules and ions kind of naked, with very high TD activity or chemical potential, respectively.
Additionally, there are formed minor entities much more reactive than a molecule of an acid itself.
The negative charge partially stabilizes the anion against being reduced and these acids are generally less stable than their anions. Of course acids can dissociate. So what?
Molecular nitric acid are much better oxidants that nitrate.
The extreme anion and hydronium activities and low water activity are helping in formation or keeping of neutral acid molecules and other entities.
Consider concentrated solutions of nitrates at high temperatures. They have minimal oxidation power. Hydronium increases nitrate oxidative power just indirectly, by equilibrium formation of entities of greater oxidation power.
The probable iron oxidative mechanism in concentrated or fuming nitric acid:
$$\ce{3 HNO3 <=> H3O+ + NO2^+ + 2 NO3-}$$
$$\ce{Fe(s)-(e-) + NO2^+ -> Fe+(s) + NO2}$$
$$\ce{Fe^3+(s)-Fe -> Fe(s) + Fe^3+}$$
By $\ce{Fe+(s)}$ is formally meant a bulk, solid iron with a single positive net charge.
But the complete system of reactions involves nitrogen in oxidation states +II, +III, +IV, +V.

Would the molecular acid, donate proton (e.g HNO3 --> H+ + NO3-) and then the anion that isn't hydrated and stabilized unlike in dilute solution react (Mechanism). H+ gains electrons to form H2(g)

Very diluted acid does react forming hydrogen.

How does HNO3 --> H3O+. Shouldn't it be H+ since it is CONCENTRATED FUMING acid where there is barely any water.

Fuming acidhas>98%, red fuming also disloved NO2. We spoke mostly bout 68% forming azeotrope with maximum b.p. 68% has nominal ration about 1.6 : 1 H2O : HNO3 // About water itself even in fuming HNO3, see the first equilibrium reaction. // H+ as a proton is not found in any liquid with molecules having a free electron pair, and hardly even in liquids without it.
